# Prometheus relabel_configs - support multiple scrape locations in 1 job

Tags: prometheus

A custom exporter is installed on 2 hosts, and it can monitor three environments each.
I use relabel_configs to ensure that the appropriate host is used per environment
But the below section leads to 2 different jobnames  (myJob_1 and myJob_2)

```
 - job_name: myJob_1
    metrics_path: /probe
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ tld , tle, tlf ]

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: host1:8112

  - job_name: myJob_2
    metrics_path: /probe
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ tod , toe, tof]

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: host2:8112
```

Is there a possibility to merge the different targets into 1 job?
I don't know how to configure the relabel_config section achieve it.

```
 - job_name: myJob
    metrics_path: /probe
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ tld , tle, tlf ]
        labels:
           host: host1:8112
      - targets: [ tod , toe, tof ]
        labels:
           host: host2:8112

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: ?????????????
```

(Used version prometheus 2.37.0)

I would appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following config:

```yaml
- job_name: myJob
    metrics_path: /probe
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ tld , tle, tlf ]
        labels:
           host: host1:8112
      - targets: [ tod , toe, tof ]
        labels:
           host: host2:8112

    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        source_labels: [host]
```

It puts the label `host` into the label `__address__`, so Prometheus or [vmagent](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/vmagent.html) scrapes the address defined in the `host` label per each [static_config](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/sd_configs.html#static_configs).

See more details about `__address__` pseudo-label in [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config).

Comment: When I use "source_labels:[host] ", I get an unmarshall error "cannot unmarshal !!seq into string.

So I tried with source_labels: host".
But in that case I don't see any request from prometheus service arriving at the host1:8112 port: (which is logical as the the host is then treated as actual literal and it does not refer to the value specified as label host

Comment: The `cannot unmarshal !!seq into string` error usually points to incorrectly formatted yaml. Make sure that the yaml is properly formatted. Pay especial attention to leading whitespace per each line. Also try swapping `source_labels` with `target_label` in the last relabeling rule, so it has the same order of entries as the previous relabeling rules.

Comment: I did not implement your recommendation correctly. Your initial answer was fully correct. Sorry for the confusion